# Migrate user mailbox calendar to public folder (shared calendar) in Exchange

Tags: powershell, exchange

We use Exchange 2016. A user shares his calendar with other users through Outlook (2010, 2013). To decouple this calendar from his mailbox and make it a shared calendar, we want to port it to a public folder preferably using PowerShell.

So far, we have exported (not even sure if this succeeded) the calendar with:

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox a.user -IncludeFolders "#Calendar#" -FilePath \\PST\user.pst
```

How do we import the `user.pst` in to a public folder?

Comment: The easiest way to import it to a Public Folder calendar is with Outlook.

Comment: Just drag and drop the calendar from the mailbox to the public folder? But, what's the difficult way? Is it through PowerShell?

Comment: `But, what's the difficult way? Is it through PowerShell?` - Are you looking for a difficult way? What's the end goal? Is it to get the content into the Public Folder? If so, why not use the easiest method?

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a PowerShell way out of curiosity. Apart from that, the easiest way is the way to go ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command to import it.
New-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox  PF -FilePath \SERVER01\PSTFiles\xxxx.pst -TargetRootFolder "xxxx"
Or you can try the following steps to import it through EAC.
1.Generating a sharing folder for performing import task
2.Enabling permission to perform import operation
3.Import PST into public folder of Exchange 2016
For details, [Learn How to Import PST into Public Folder Exchange 2013](https://www.acquireforensics.com/blog/import-pst-into-public-folder-exchange-2013.html)